# UI is not updating consistently in WinForms

Tags: winforms

I have a bit of a problem on updating my UIs.

I have an SQL Broker listening to a column (fight_isclosed) that changes value from time-to-time.

The value of said column is updating on the Console without fail but not consistently in the UI. I made a `textBox1` to check the value. Sometimes, the `fightIsClosedValue` says it's 1 but the `textBox1` is still showing "Open", sometimes it works fine.

The `DisableControls()` and `EnableControls()` are not consistently updating either.

```
public void StartListening()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cam_connString))
    {
        // Open the connection
        connection.Open();

        // Create a new instance of the Service Broker queue
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RECEIVE TOP(1) conversation_handle, message_body FROM FightStatusChangedQueue", connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Process the received message
                    var conversationHandle = reader.GetSqlGuid(0);
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
                    {
                        var messageBodyBytes = (byte[])reader.GetSqlBinary(1);
                        string messageBodyString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(messageBodyBytes); 
                        
                        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        string cleanedMessageBodyString = RemoveBomCharacter(messageBodyString);
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(cleanedMessageBodyString);

                        XmlNodeList messageNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//FightStatusChangedMessage");
                        foreach (XmlNode messageNode in messageNodes)
                        {
                            XmlNode fightIsClosedNode = messageNode.SelectSingleNode("fight_isclosed");
                            int fightIsClosedValue = int.Parse(fightIsClosedNode.InnerText);

                           
                            if (fightIsClosedValue == 1)
                            {
                                if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                                {
                                    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> if Closed " + fightIsClosedValue);
                                        textBox1.Text = "CLOSE";
                                        DisableControls();
                                    }));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> else Closed " + fightIsClosedValue);
                                    textBox1.Text = "CLOSE";
                                    DisableControls();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                                {
                                    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> if Open " + fightIsClosedValue);
                                        textBox1.Text = "OPEN";
                                        EnableControls();
                                    }));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> else Open " + fightIsClosedValue);
                                    textBox1.Text = "OPEN";
                                    EnableControls();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // End the conversation once the message is processed
                    using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(cam_connString))
                    {
                        conn2.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand endConversationCommand = new SqlCommand("END CONVERSATION @conversation_handle", conn2))
                        {
                            endConversationCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conversation_handle", conversationHandle);
                            endConversationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        conn2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I tried so far**

I tried enclosing the block of code where it's supposed to update the UI with

`if(!textBox1.IsDisposed)` as well as `if(IsHandleCreated)` I also tried using `textBox1.BeginInvoke`. Sometimes it does update for quite some time, but then starts acting up again.

Something like this:

```
if (!textBox1.IsDisposed)
{
    if (IsHandleCreated)
    {
        if (camBettingIsClosedValue >= 1)
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> if Closed " + camBettingIsClosedValue);
                    textBox1.Text = "CLOSE";
                    DisableControls();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> else Closed " + camBettingIsClosedValue);
                    textBox1.Text = "CLOSE";
                    DisableControls();
                }));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> if Open " + camBettingIsClosedValue);
                    textBox1.Text = "OPEN";
                    EnableControls();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE ISCLOSED: -> else Open " + camBettingIsClosedValue);
                    textBox1.Text = "OPEN";
                    EnableControls();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```